# Stop Scrolling if there is no Content left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want this script to stop scrolling if clicked, when there is no more content left in the div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#right").click(function () { 
        var leftPos = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
        $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 250}, 800);
    });   

    $("#left").click(function () { 
        var leftPos2 = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
        $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos2 - 250}, 800);
    });   
});
```

This is the demo link: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/UHmJ2/)

In the demo, it keeps scrolling to the right side although the div has no content anymore to show. I want it to stop.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't really work, but just by toying around with it I see you set a fixed width to the element containing the text: `width:90000px;`. This means that even if the content is less or greater than 90000px in length, thediv will always be 90000px

Comment: So, how to make it works without set a fixed position and width value?

Comment: I just answered your question below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `white-space: nowrap` to your `#midleBody` element and remove the `width: 90000px` from it.

What happens is that your element has a fixed width, so your javascript detects it and keeps going till the end. You need to have the element adjust dynamically in accordance to the text inside of it instead, thats what `white-space:nowrap` does.

Comment: Hi, can you repair my code? It's very bad when I put it in html code. I just wrote it in Fiddle and it looks good, but when I move it to html file, I am just aware that the right div is in fixed position with "right is 0" so that it separate far away from middle divs. I hope you understand what I am talking about.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Here I update the demo Fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/UHmJ2/4/  I want the wraper now is 80% with the margin is auto so that it positioned the all div to the center of the body. But the point is I want the left div and the right div which are functioned as button to be located besides the middle div.